# Accessing a struct within a struct

Tags: c, struct

If I have something like:

```
struct foo {
    struct bar {
         char name[8];
         int temp;
    } example[100];
};
```

If I wanted to get what `name` is, how would I do so for say the first element in the array?

Comment: Rather "what `name` **are**". There's no *one* `name`, since it's the member of a struct of which there's a whole **array** (inside the outer struct). So, until you tell me *which* name you want to access, I can't help :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    struct bar {
         char name[8];
         int temp;
    } example[100];
};


int main(void) {
  struct foo my_foo;
  printf("%s\n", my_foo.example[0].name);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need printf here: just `puts` the string directly

Comment: @ahcox: `printf("%s\n", my_foo.example[0].name);` will to the same thing as `puts(my_foo.example[0].name);`.

Comment: @HermanZvonimirDošilović Just saying you don't need it. It is a more complex function. More code in that line here. Do the simplest thing. <shrug>

Comment: @rowan.G: If there's no `%` in `name`.

Comment: @ahcox I agree with you, but I think that the most important thing here is that the user3268401 understood the answer on his question. :)

Comment: @HermanZvonimirDošilović Absolutely, I was the first person to upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check if your code compiles, but that would be something like:

```
foo var;
var.example[0].name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct foo myfoo;
char * the_name;

/* initialize myfoo ... */

the_name = myfoo.example[0].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct foo var;
printf("name -- %s\n", var.example[0].name);
```

NOTE :
i advice you to abbreviate your strcut like this :

```
typedef struct foo foo;
struct foo {
    struct bar {
         char name[8];
         int temp;
    } example[100];
};
```

like this you will not be obliged to declare your vars like this :

```
struct foo var;
```

but

```
foo var;
```

Good luck ;